# how to nest a visual webpart inside another?

Tags: web-part, deployment

I just wanna insert a visual webpart inside another, I'm using this tag to register the inserted web part like this:

<%@ Register Src="~/PL/VisualWebPart1/VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx" TagName="VisualWebPartx" TagPrefix="bassel" %>

after I deploy this sharepoint project, I add the webpart to a page either through the web interface or the designer.

the result is this error message:
"/PL/VisualWebPart1/VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx' is not allowed on this page"

anybody knows the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by registering as assembly instead, like this:

<%@ Register assembly="Forum, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=645bd5a85fdb995f" namespace="Forum.PL.BreadCrump" tagprefix="uc1" %>

this worked fine. but I was wondering if there's another method.